# It seems that Chrome is downloading something continuously and daily but nothing seems to download?

Tags: google-chrome, download

It seems that Chrome is downloading something continuously and daily but nothing seems to download? It happening daily mostly all time.

I have attached screenshots.

#### Image 1

Here you see chrome tab in task bar seems to downloading something.

> [image: image1]

#### Image 2

See while exiting the chrome it shows pop up of downloading something.

> [image: image2]

#### Image 3

But there is nothing seems to download in download tab.

> [image: Iimage3]

Comment: Maybe the Chrome profile is corrupted. // Got any exotic extensions installed?

Comment: Try opening it in safe mode. Then enable one by one your extensions to see if one of them is the culprit.

Comment: @DanielB in my college mail id profile of chrome there is no extension present. But same problem is occuring.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran I un-installed chrome & again installed but same problem

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, I think that the problem is that you have downloaded files in the past, but they are no longer available on your machine. Chrome is trying to do something with them, and that's why you are getting that message. I've had that same thing happen to me before.

Try clearing all your download history, and browsing data. (Settings >>> Privacy and Security >>> Clear Browsing Data). Make sure you tick at least **Download History** for **All Time**. If possible, try to clear everything just to be safe.

If for some reason that doesn't fix the problem, try creating a new profile.

Comment: This fixed it for me. First time I saw this happen. (Currently have a metered connection so it was really important.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue; not really fixed the way that people on a metered connection would like :
https://crbug.com/1311753

[https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/157884177/chrome-appearing-to-download-without-me-downloading-anything?hl=en#:~:text=The%20team%20confirmed](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/157884177/chrome-appearing-to-download-without-me-downloading-anything?hl=en#:%7E:text=The%20team%20confirmed)

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/u59r5t/optimizationguidepredictionmodels_phantom/